# call a function from firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, google-cloud-functions

Probably it's a simple question, but I can't understand how to do it.
I would like to call a function from another function in Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
exports.firstFunction = functions.https.onCall((params, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return secondFunction()  // how can I call secondFunction?
      .then((resp) => resolve(resp))
      .catch((e) => reject(e));
  });
});

exports.secondFunction = functions.https.onCall((params, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve("secondFunction");
  });
});
```

Making `httpCallable("secondFunction")` return the correct string. If I do `httpCallable("firstFunction")` I have an `[Error: INTERNAL]`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look:

```
exports.firstFunction = functions.https.onCall((params, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return secondFunctionHandler()
      .then((resp) => resolve(resp))
      .catch((e) => reject(e));
  });
});

const secondFunctionHandler = (params, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve("secondFunction");
  });
};

exports.secondFunction = functions.https.onCall(secondFunctionHandler);
```

I like separating all my cloud functions into "handlers" (written in separate files and then imported) and single lines in the index file, not only the ones I want to reuse. It find it makes the code more readable and manageable.

Comment: With ```firebase deploy --only functions```, is ```secondFunctionHandler()``` uploaded on the Firebase Cloud?

Comment: `secondFunctionHandler` is just a variable. It's like doing `const one = 1`. Is `one` uploaded on the Firebase Cloud?

Comment: @Stratubas in the workflow you described, do you have to initialize your database and other Firebase resources multiple times, once in each function file?

Comment: Other than `admin`, what other resources need to be initialized? I do like exporting a `db` variable (which is just `admin.firestore()`) for readability purposes.